# Why AND && logic is used in chained commands in most shells, not OR || logic

Tags: bash, shell, logic

I am curious about the logic behind `&&` in continuous commands execution in shell.

Lets see an example: `command_a && command_b && command_c`

In shell, this means that once a command fails, the consequent commands will not execute and the chain should stop.

If we replace each command by its exit code, the chain becomes, for example this expression `0 && 1 && 0`. (`command_a` succeed, `command_b` failed, `command_c` succeed)

If we try evaluating this expression, the evaluation should stop right after the first command, `0` value.

If `&&` logic is replaced by `||`, the expression would be more fit to the meaning of original chained command.
`0 || 1 || 0`.

Expression's evaluation stops after `command_b` execution

Comment: Hint: exit code 0 is TRUE and 1 is FALSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a difference between the semantics of a successful command and the representation of success via the numeric value of the exit code.  If you consider the abstract "is a command successful", && makes more sense, since the "success" abstract boolean is true.  That's why && is used.  You need `A` to run, AND you need `B` to run.

But, due to the fact that there's usually only one status for success, but many different types of errors, the value 0 has been defined long ago to be used for exit status to indicate success.

So, the exit status of a command can simply not replace the command itself in such an expression.  The semantics and the representation are just different.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24684/confusing-use-of-and-operators).

"The right side of && will only be evaluated if the exit status of the left side is zero. || is the opposite: it will evaluate the right side only if the left side exit status is nonzero..."

```
$ false && echo howdy!

$ true && echo howdy!
howdy!
$ true || echo howdy!

$ false || echo howdy!
howdy!
```

Comment: FYI, "code snippets" are for HTML -- content that can run in a browser -- which is why your question right now has a "Run code snippet" button that doesn't actually do anything. Use the `{}` button or four-space indents for other code-formatting.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for that tip!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen `||` used in some shell script too. I think it depends on the occasions. You may use `command-a && command-b` when you want `command-b` to be executed only after `command-a` success.

Likewise, you may use `command-a || command-b` to deal with the situation when `command-a` fails.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After reading your question three times I now understand what puzzles you: That 0 represents success, and/or (sic) that logical operators treat it as `true`. Yes, that can be confusing, coming from C. The other Peter's answer explains that well. I let my original answer stand anyway because it is not "wrong".

---

It is what logic dictates if commands are impossible to perform or don't make sense unless their predecessors succeeded. That happens quite often: "Retrieve a HTML document from the web, verify the time stamp, parse a value out of it, and write that value as an updated data somewhere." Each step depends on the success of all preceding steps.

If, instead, you have something "retrieve a document from the web, or from the cache, or from disk, or take a default here document, in this order of preference", then the appropriate way to write that is indeed with logical ORs. This happens but is less common.

ORing is a common idiom though for error handling, because subsequent commands are exactly performed if the pervious failed. Consider Perl's idiomatic `cmd() || die();`. (You have more lives. Phew.)

Comment: ...though for purposes of exit status, it's true in C too -- see the constants `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` defined in `stdlib.h`.